# Unexpected result when parsing with BeautifulSoup and regex

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am playing around with the BeautifulSoup library. I was trying to parse an email from the website, but got an unexpected result. This is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from urllib.error import URLError

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from urllib.parse import quote 

startUrl = "http://getrocketbook.com/pages/returns"
try:
    html = urlopen(quote((startUrl).encode('utf8'), ':/?%#_'))
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    alls = bsObj.body.findAll(text=re.compile('[A-Za-z0-9\._+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+'))
    for al in alls:
        print(al)
except HTTPError:
    pass
except URLError:
    pass
```

I expected to parse just an email, but I actually parsed this sentenced instead:

```
If you’ve done all of this and you still have not received your refund yet, please contact us at hello@getrocketbook.com.
```

Any idea what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `findAll()` looks for actual elements or text nodes, not for separate words.

What you need to do is to *apply the same compiled regular expression to the result*:

```
pattern = re.compile('[A-Za-z0-9\._+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+')
alls = bsObj.body.find_all(text=pattern)
for al in alls:
    print(pattern.search(al).group(0))
```

Also, since there is a single email there, see if you can use the `find()` method instead.